# Calling Backbone.Model.Save converts child-Backbone.Model to object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating a Backbone Model which has a child Backbone Model inside of it:

```
console.log("inside add item, video:", video instanceof Backbone.Model);

var playlistItem = new PlaylistItem({
    video: video,
    title: video.get('title')
});
```

afterwards, I save it:

```
playlistItem.save({}, {
    success: function() {
        console.log("Successfully saved.");
        playlistItem.get('video').get('title');
    }
});
```

In this example, I encounter an error -- video is not an instanceof Backbone.Model after calling save. Why?

Comment: Are you saving to a server?  If so, what data is the server expecting from the save?  When you save, the model calls `toJSON`, and it wont know how to serialize your child model.

Comment: I am saving to a server and the data gets to my server perfectly fine. I receive a full Video object containing all the appropriate properties. I return a JSON representation of my PlaylistItem and child Video object after returning from the save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to override `parse` and `toJSON`.

```
  toJSON: function() {
     var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);

     // replace backbone model with json.
     json.video = this.get('video').toJSON();

     return json;
  },

  parse: function(data) {
     // take json of video and set into model.
     this.get('video').set(data.video);
     delete data.video;

     return data;
  },
```

If you don't parse the json data like this, backbone is going to take the 'video' object from the json and overwrite your Backbone model.

Comment: How come I need to override both and not just parse? The JSON seems to be working ok..?

Comment: It is strange, are you using something like backbone-relational or something similar?  The default `toJSON` just clones the attributes of the model, which does a shallow copy, so you would be sending a Backbone model to the server for 'video', not just the json attributes for the video.  On the server, do you have to use `data.video.attributes.name` to access the video stuff?  If you override toJSON it would be `data.video.name`.

Comment: I'm not using Backbone.Relational, but I am using MVC4. I suppose the model binder is properly handling whatever Backbone is sending to it, but Backbone does not handle MVC's response appropriately..?

Comment: Well, I am surprised it works on the server, but if the server sends back 'video' in json form, it will overwrite your Backbone model with that json, unless you fix it in parse.

Comment: Yup. You're correct and I am surprised as well. Adding the parse bit fixes things. Thank you :)